# What is known about when regularity properties only hold for partial boldface pointclasses?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, computability-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Apologies in advance for a rather vague and open-ended question.

Results about regularity properties of the projective pointclasses tend to have a wholesale flavor. By this I mean one tends to be concerned about (say) the measurability of the $\mathbf\Sigma^1_n$ sets and/or obtains models where measurability holds for all sets in a certain boldface pointclass (for example, under Martin's axiom and $\neg\mathsf{CH}$, all the $\mathbf\Sigma^1_2$ sets are measurable and have the property of Baire).

Or alternatively they have proofs that relativize: an example would be the equivalence between the measurability of $\Sigma^1_2(x)$ and the statement that almost all reals are random over $L[x]$. Or the equivalence between $\Pi^1_1(x)$-determinacy and the existence of $x^\#$.

I wonder what is known about statements of the following form, where $A$ is some set of reals of interest: for all $x\in A$, all the $\Sigma^1_n(x)$ sets have certain regularity property, while for some $y\notin A$, $\Sigma^1_n(y)$ does not. Are there works done on these statements? What is their relation to the more familiar axioms and models?

I would appreciate pointers for literature or keywords to search for. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean "some" of the \Sigma^1_n(y), for $y\not\in A$? They always share $\Sigma^1_n$-sets.

Comment: @喻良 yes, that's right. Thanks for catching that typo!

Comment: It's rather easy to get such separation at the $\Sigma^1_2$ level. Suppose that $x\in L[y]$ and $\omega_1^{L[x]} < \omega_1^{L[y]}$, then in $L[y]$ we have $\Sigma^1_2(y)$-instances of your favourite pathological sets. However, $\Sigma^1_2(x)$ sets will be regular. For example, since $\omega_1^{L[x]} < \omega_1$ in $L[y]$, it follows by a theorem of Tornquist that there are no $\Sigma^1_2(x)$-mad families. Similarly, since $\omega_1^{L[x]}$ is countable in $L[y]$, almost all reals in $L[y]$ are random/Cohen over $L[x]$, so we get $\Sigma^1_2(x)$ Lebesgue measurability/Baire property.

Comment: (cont) This can probably be extended to higher levels of the projective hierarchy, but you're going to need some inner model theory for that, e.g., to get $\Sigma^1_3(x)$ measurability you'll need something in the spirit of Theorem 5.3 in this paper of Ikegami: http://www.sic.shibaura-it.ac.jp/~ikegami/ikegami-fa-reg-final.pdf